# pyperclip copies only the last item on list cocatenation to clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x

Totally a newbie to python. Please, i need pyperclip to copy the result of print to clipboard on this code.

```
print ('These generates image variation titles and a .jpg file extension added to each number.')
vartop = []
while True:
print('Enter the variation ID ' + str(len(vartop) + 1) + ' (or Enter to Generate.):')
myVar = input()
if myVar == '':
    break
    vartop = vartop + [myVar]
print('Variations are: ')
for myVar in vartop:
print (myVar + '.jpg') #I want this result to be copied to the clipboard.
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(myVar + '.jpg') #This code copies only the last generated line to the clipboard.
print ('Variations Copied to clipboard.')
```

This is the result i want to be copied.

```
10.jpg
20.jpg
```

But only the last line which is "20.jpg" copies to the clipboard.

```
20.jpg
```

Comment: You can make one string and then copy it with `pyperclip`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can yo u explain in detail? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyperclip.copy()` accepts a single string.  Using a modified example:

**Given**

```
import pyperclip


filenames = [f"{x}.jpg" for x in range(10, 30, 10)]
```

The results are some group of strings:

```
filenames
# ['10.jpg', '20.jpg']
```

**Code**

Join the filenames into a single string, separated by newlines:

```
"\n".join(filenames)
# '10.jpg\n20.jpg'
```

**Demo**

Copy the last result with an underscore `_`:

```
pyperclip.copy(_)
```

Paste results, e.g. `Ctrl + V`:

```
10.jpg
20.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks so much @pylang. Your solution  `filenames = [f"{x}.jpg" for x in range(10, 30, 10)]`    works if i wanted to generate a specific range. But here, i want to generate the "filenames" from the multiple user input() and print using pyperclip.

Comment: Thanks @pylang after so many hours, i managed to solve it. Thanks for helping with pointers. I appreciate. I will post the solution right out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where `pyperclip.copy` only copied last string of my print function to the clipboard and i wanted it to copy the whole output. This is the solution i came up with some pointers from @pylang .

```
print ('These generates image variation titles and a .jpg file extension added to    each number.')
vartop = []
while True:
print('Enter the variation ID ' + str(len(vartop) + 1) + ' (or Enter to Generate.):')
myVar = input()
if myVar == '':
    break
vartop = vartop + [myVar + '.jpg'] #I added the file extension to the list Concatenation
print('Variations are: ')
for myVar in vartop:
print(myVar)
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy("\n".join(vartop + [myVar])) #Using a list separator "\n", i added the code i wanted in my clipboard to the pyperclip.copy without the file extension.
print ('Variation Titles Copied to clipboard.')
```

Now the whole user `input()` with the `'.jpg'` extension is generated and copied to the clipboard using pyperclip.

Comment: Great job.  Glad you resolved it on your own.  And welcome to Python!